# How to read members of a custom VBA class object, passed as a COM__Object, with VB.net? (UIPath)

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, com

I have a VBA Function which returns an object of my own class module "CInputDBEntries".

UIPath receives this object as a COM__Object and to read it I need to do some CType Conversion. However no matter how I do it, I can't access the members (values) of the object.

I already tried to convert it to "Object" but can't access the values.
I also tried saving multiple class objects as a Collection but it fails at the CType conversion because it's bugged (VBACollection to Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection = COM CastTypeException)

I also posted this on the UIPath forums: https://forum.uipath.com/t/invoke-vba-how-to-read-the-retrieved-com-object-in-uipath-vba-function-returns-custom-type/96115

Class Definition:

```
Private strTitle As String
Private strValue As String
Private boolIntegrity As Boolean
```

The method:

```
Public Function ReadRelevantEntries() As CInputDBEntries
   Dim entry As CInputDBEntries

   entry.Title = "title"
   entry.Val = "value"
   entry.Integrity = True

   Set ReadRelevantEntries = entry
End Function
```

Currently my conversion is this: CType(listExcelEntries, Object)

Expected result is to be able to pull the values out of the COM__Object so I can read the 2 strings and my bool variable.

Comment: If you're using COM, then presumably you're working against some kind of type library?  The easiest way to do things is to convert the type library to an interop library (automatically or manually using tlbimp) and then work through the interop library.  Usually, if the type library is written correctly, it just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

**This is the wrong approach**

```
var propertyInfo = comObject.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName")
```

**This is the correct approach**

```
//get the value of comObject.PropertyName
object propertyValue = comObject.GetType().InvokeMember("PropertyName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null);
```

Credits: https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/c-using-reflection-with-com-objects/